# Casting "pointer to data" to "pointer to function"

Tags: c++, c

As I know such casting from *pointer to data* to *pointer to function* is not allowed in C89, C99. What about C++?

Comment: I'm curious what's the purpose of such cast.

Comment: Test use case - You decide to impl. smth. like winapi RegisterClass https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx and you decide to declare a field lpfnWndProc as (void*).  The question is: "Is it legal or not?"

Comment: @bruzzo - `void` pointers are "special". You should have mentioned it earlier :) That's why I asked.

Comment: My mistake: not disallowed, but conditionally supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: An implementation is not required to support such a cast.

It may allow a `reinterpret_cast` to do it, subject to certain rules (essentially: converting to object pointer and back has to yield the original pointer).

Quoth the standard, [expr.reinterpret.cast]/8:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

Non-embedded implementations usually allow it for purposes of dynamic linking (such as `dlsym()`). Strictly speaking, though, it is not required to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems that it is from C++11 standart. But I can't found anything in C++2003 standart...( I think such things is similar, even if It is no mentioned in ISO/IEC 14882:2003